# Firefox webdriver is working where as Phanthon Js is not

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

The below script is working in firefox but doesn't work in Phanthon Js

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
// Enter UserName
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@type='text']")).sendKeys("admin");
// Enter Password
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@type='password']")).sendKeys(
        "admin");
// Wait For Page To Load
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Click on 'Sign In' button
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@type='button']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement webElement =    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'OK')]"));
webElement.click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'Process')]"))
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
{"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath 
'.//span[contains(text(),'Process')]'","request":{"headers":{"Accept-
Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-
Length":"60","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-
8","Host":"localhost:32339","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 
(Java/1.8.0_60)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":".......
```

For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

1. Why Phanthon JS refused to work when it works fine using firefox web driver?
2. How to run the program headless i.e without browser which has the compatability with firefox webdriver code?
3. Alternative way to quickly prepare a script for headless?

Comment: PhantomJS is a different browser with different behavior and its own bugs. You can't run PhantomJS with the compatibility level of Firefox. Have you verified that you're on the correct page by taking a screenshot? Which PhantomJS version are you using?

Comment: How to take a screen shot? I am using PhantomJS 1.0.1

Comment: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getScreenshotAs-org.openqa.selenium.OutputType- And you're almost certainly not using version 1.0.1. Please check the actual PhantomJS version and not the Ghostdriver version.